# UglifyJS changes the code bahaviour

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I have the following code (simplified for the sake of discussion):

```
var a = 1;
var b = [];
if (checkIfAisOne(a)) {
    b = ['something']
}
console.log(b);
//['something']
```

then there is a Grunt Uglify task which converts this code to this:

```
checkIfAisOne(a) || (b = ['something']), console.log(b);
// []
```

Because the first part of the expression is true, the second part (after `||`) is not executed and therefore `b` remains unchanged.

So, uglified code shows different output than non-uglified code.

Is that a known issue? A bug? How it can be prevented, is there any option/setting to fix this?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. those should be equivalent. perhaps the missing semicolon has something to do with it.

Comment: @DanielA.White Shouldn't it be `&&` rather than `||`?

Comment: I would expect a ternary operator here..

Comment: @JamesThorpe yea read it wrong in my head.

Comment: @DanielA.White This is the verifiable code :) I could add `function checkIfAisOne(a) {return a === 1}`

Comment: @strah what versions are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.9.2

Comment: i tried it on an online tool. perhaps switching to a newer version might work

Comment: @strah what command did you run to uglify your code?

Comment: @strah which "uglify" are you using? [`uglify-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js), [`uglify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify), or something else entirely? The "0.9.2" version that you say you're using doesn't match up with either of those two.

Comment: It's [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify). However it seems to be a bug. After changing some unrelated code somewhere else and running the uglifier everything seems to be OK and the resulting code has `&&` as @JamesThorpe suggested. The code in question hastn't changed and the whole code is checked for lint errors before uglifying, so a missing semicolon or something like that shouldn't have contributed. Weird (or the problem is elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest uglifyJS is producing this output:

```
var a=1,b=[];checkIfAisOne(a)&&(b=["something"]),console.log(b);
```

Using https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/commit/a0e03c9df47c411a40bceef02af2ce3dd1a329cc, which is committed on 3/5/2016 but merged in repo 4/5/2016. The output is the same for UglifyJS v2.6.2.

UglifyJS v2.6.2 is shipped with grunt-contrib-uglify 1.0.0 and later. So please upgrade grunt-contrib-uglify if necessary.

If there is still a problem with the output, feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 with the code snippet